# IIS: Auto-blacklisting flooding IPs?

Tags: iis, flooding

Right now, we a have a site that is flooded and the site is very slow. Normally it is working well but someone decided to flood it today. We have other sites on the server and they are not directly affected. We have limited the amount of CPU that the flooded site may use.

We really need a solution to avoid flooding of sites like this case.

I have read this page:
http://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/8-tips-secure-iis-installation/

It tells about temporarily dening IP addresses but it does not say for how long the IPs are denied access.

In addition, I rather like that the IPs were auto-blocked in IIS or even better in the Windows firewall. Is this possible?

Can someone help so the site can start behaving normally again? :-)

We are using IIS version 8.5 :-)

Comment: What version of IIS you are using?

Comment: We are using IIS version 8.5 :-)

Comment: When such requests arrive on the server, any blocking is too late. Consider a dedicate firewall server in front, or use public solution such as CloudFlare.